# How to create query that searches for field equals string or int

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongodb collection where the userId field is sometimes an int and sometimes a string. (55 or "55")

Using the .NET driver, I create query parts based on a `MongoDBLogEntry` class:

```
var filters = new List<FilterDefinition<MongoDBLogEntry>>();
foreach (var docFilter in docFilters)
{
    var key = docFilter.Key; // Example: "userId"
    var value = docFilter.Value;  // Example: "55"

    FilterDefinition<MongoDBLogEntry> filter;
    if (key.EndsWith("Id"))
    {
        var intfilter = builder.Eq(key, BsonInt32.Create(Convert.ToInt32(value)));
        var stringFilter = builder.Eq(key, value);
        var orFilter = builder.Or(intfilter, stringFilter);
        filter = orFilter;
    }
    else
    {
        filter = builder.Eq(docFilter.Key, value);
    }

    filters.Add(filter);
}
```

Because my data has string or int for some fields, my `MongoDBLogEntry` class defines userId field as a string, with a `StringOrIntSerializer : SerializerBase<string>` serializer on those fields.

My issue is that the query that is created for one of the id fields is:

```
{ "$or" : [{ "userId" : "55" }, { "userId" : "55" }] }
```

I've also tried an `$in` clause, that that also ends up being two string values, `"55", "55"`

I *think* I understand why those are being converted to strings... because my `MongoDBLogEntry` class defines the field that way and converts all values to a string.

**But is there a way for me to force an `int` into the query with the code above?**

Comment: I guess I know the answer but... Can you not change your data model to have properly typed data as in either strings or ints on any given field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above I would suggest you attempt to "clean up" your data in a way that every field has a predictable data type. That makes it a lot easier to deal with...

Nonetheless you can always resort to using the string based version:

```
var orFilter = builder.Or("{ \"userId\": 55 }", stringFilter);
```

Comment: My apps not inserting strings instead of ints would be ideal, but I cannot fix legacy bugs immediately. Constantly polling and fixing the DB is not something I want to do.  So in order to make this work right now, I need to use your suggested solution, which worked great.